# What is the difference between a spring rest template and javax.ws.rs client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs

Javax.ws.rs client implementation

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Response response = client.target(URI.contextPathUI + "/api/item").request().get();
```

Spring rest template implementation

```
HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
param.put("id", itemId);
return restTemplate.getForObject(URI.contextPathUI + "/api/item", ArrayList.class, param);
```

Answer (score -2):

The difference lies what you are building your functionality against, in each case.

For the JAX-RS Client case, you are building your code on top of a specification JAX-RS. This specification doesn't have any implementation for the `Client`, so you also must depend on an implementation such as Jersey, which is fully compliant with the JAX-RS spec.

In the Spring Rest Template case, this is a non-JAX-RS compliant implementation. The Spring Rest Template is part of the whole Spring ecosystem, which is separate from the Java EE ecosystem that JAX-RS belongs to (Java / Jakarta EE).

Comment: I meant client class in javax.ws.rs.client package, is there a difference between using that or spring rest template. Is one btter than the other in someway ?